# Getting ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME when trying to use OAuth with a Chrome Custom Tab

Tags: android, google-chrome, oauth, chrome-custom-tabs

I am building an Android app that utilizes the Digital Ocean API. To authenticate, the app opens a Chrome Custom Tab to the Digital Ocean OAuth page. I have my redirect URI set to `myapp://authorize/` and have registered that in my Android Manifest with the following:

```
    <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="authorize"
                    android:scheme="myapp" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
```

After Digital Ocean redirects to my url (`myapp://authorize/?code=accesstokenhere`), the custom tab gives me ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

However, the URL works just fine in the emulator's Browser application.

Comment: In your scenario, is a user action necessary to trigger the redirect, or does it happen automatically?

Comment: @andreban After the user enters their credentials on the login form and submits it, Digital Ocean redirects them to the uri (```myapp://authorize/?code=token```). Not sure if that's counting as automatic (Digital Ocean does redirect them to it) or user triggered (User must first login).

Comment: Have you tried again with the latest chrome version ? This issue seems to be fixed right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming what @Jejefcgb said, this issue is fixed in the latest version of Chrome.